# Backbonejs: Customise the model object before being sent/synced to the server

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Am parsing data coming from the servers through the `parse` method provided by backbone.

```
var the_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
   parse: function(response) {
      return {
            id: ApiWrapper.getId(response.resource_uri),
            resourceUri: response.resource_uri,
            categoryId: response.alert_type_id,
            latitude: response.latitude,
            longitude: response.longitude,
            utm: MapCoordinates.latLongToUTM(response.latitude, response.longitude),
            categoryName: response.alert_type_name,
            ranger: {
                fullName: response.ranger_id.first_name + ' ' + response.ranger_id.last_name
            },
            icon: "/images/map-icons/map-alert-0" + response.alert_type_id + ".png",
            dateTime: moment(response.time_stamp).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
        }
   }
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: the_model
   parse: function(data_from_server) {
       return data_from_server.results
   }
})
```

In order to sync any newly added data back to the server - since the server will not accept the parsed format backbone persists - how would I go by this? Practically un-parse the data or reformat the model(s) before being synced to the server.

Answer (score 1):

To control how your model sends back data to your server, override [`Model.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync) and set the `attrs` attribute in the options :

```
var the_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        // ...
    },

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};

        if ((method==='create') || (method==='update')) {
            // prepare the data you want to send
            var data = {
                resource_uri: this.get('resourceUri'),
                alert_type_id: this.get('categoryId')
                // other attributes you want to add
            };

            // pass that as an option to Backbone.sync
            options.attrs = data;
        }

        return Backbone.Model.prototype.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/z31k1qtp/

Comment: `return Backbone.Model.sync.call(this, method, model, options);` Works fine without the `prototype` part too